Unable to make callouts after Salesforce Instance Refresh. Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable"
Over the weekend, Salesforce has refreshed our org instance AP53.
Since then our integration with Equifax is not working.
Whenever we try to make a callout to the Equifax servers, we get the following error
"Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable".
We are able to connect via Postman but not from our Salesforce org.
What could be the issue?
Is it a case of IP whitelisting? (But this issue only started after the instance refresh)
Any solutions or insights are greatly helpful.
Thank you.

Have you asked Equifax support?

@FelixvanHove Yes Felix, we have contacted both Equifax and Salesforce Support. Equifax support says its a salesforce issue and that other Equifax clients using salesforce are also having the same issue.

Have Salesforce support answered? :-) Jokes aside. Have you tried other integrations? Like make a callout to google.com with a search parameter?

Finally got this issue resolved. It was a case of IP Whitelisting. When our Salesforce Instance was refreshed our org IP was updated. Once Equifax whitelisted the new org IP, the integration started working as expected.
